# Expand-Collaspe Using Angular ng-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

Hello I am trying to create a grid which expand/collaspe row when click on the column data.
My grid is look like

- First show only first column data and all other column data is blank
  but their header are show.
- Next when click on '+' icon of first column then in next row it is
  expand and second column data is show and all remaing are blank.
- Next when click on '+' icon of second column then it is expand and
  third column data is show and all remaing are blank.
- So on...

For this I try to create First level and my sample is - http://plnkr.co/edit/p7NHNCRiewHAvEEuByyK?p=preview

My sample code is -

```
$scope.myData = [{icon:"",Domain: "Moroni", project:"" },
{icon:"",Domain: "Tiancum", project:"" },
{icon:"",Domain: "Jacob", project:"" },
{icon:"",Domain: "Nephi", project:"" },
{icon:"",Domain: "Enos", project: ""}];
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'icon',
        displayName: '',
        cellTemplate: '<div><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="foo(row.entity.Domain)" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)">></i></div>'
      },{
        field: 'Domain',
        displayName: 'Domain',
        cellTemplate: '<div  ng-click="foo(row.getProperty(col.field))" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)"></div>'
      }, {
        field: 'project',
        displayName: 'project'
      }

    ]
  };
```

Please suggest how I create expand/collaspe functionlity and I want to use only Angular-Grid(ng-grid).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want  [UI-grid TreeView](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_treeView)

Add  `'ui.grid.treeView'` to angular module.

Your grid template:

```
 <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-tree-view class="grid"></div>
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tAem4eebbw9Ht3S3QXLK?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: ui-grid is free or paid??

Comment: @paritaporwal its a free

Comment: how to customize ui-grid according to me?

Comment: @paritaporwal well, I gave you how it works. You can restyle everything. Its out of scope of this question. If you feel my answer is helpful - upvote. tnx